# Why does "overflow-x: hidden" not work when trying to take out the white space between divs but rather creates a scroll on the previous div?

Tags: html

This is the HTML code. The problem is down near class two and three. In between those divs is a blank space. Yes, the p code is repeated from two and three, just to avoid confusion.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
</head>
<body onload="document.body.style.opacity='1'">


<div class="one" id="mainPage">

<!-- Header -->
    <div id="infoHeader" class="header">
        <!-- Buttons -->
        <div id="header_buttons">
            <p style="text-align: center; float: right"><a style="text-decoration: none" class="button secondary-button" id="contact_button" href="#contactUs">Contact Us</a></p>
            <p style="text-align: center; float: right"><a style="text-decoration: none" class="button secondary-button" id="provide_button" href="#provide">What We Provide</a></p>
            <p style="text-align: center; float: right"><a style="text-decoration: none" class="button secondary-button" id="whyUs_button" href="#whyUs">Why Us?</a></p>
        </div>
        <!-- End of Buttons -->
    </div>
<!-- End of Header -->

<!-- Main Text on top of the background image -->
<h2 id="main_grab" align="center" style="margin-top: 15%;"> Looking for a website to kickstart your new company or business? <br> Look no more. </h2>

</div>



<div class="two" id="whyUs">    
    <div id="whyUsInfo" class="row">
    <h3 align="center" style="font-size: 35px"> Why pick us? </h3>
    <hr class="header_line">
    <br><br>
    <div style="margin-top: 6%">
        <div align="center" class="col-sm-4">
                <span id="span" style="color:white; font-size: 80px; margin-left: 5%" class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
                <h3 style="color: white; text-transform: uppercase"> You're preferences </h3>
                <p style="color: white;"> You tell us what you want the website to look like and <br> we'll start tinkering to produce the final image! </p>
        </div>
        <div align="center" class="col-sm-4">
                <span style="color:white; font-size: 80px; margin-left: 8%" class="glyphicon glyphicon-forward"></span>
                <h3 style="color: white; text-transform: uppercase"> fast and reliable </h3>
                <p style="color: white;"> Once we comfirm your request, we will being working on it <br> right away. </p>
        </div>
        <div id="oddOneOut" align="center" class="col-sm-4">
                <span style="color:white; font-size: 80px; margin-left: 5%" class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></span>
                <h3 style="color: white; text-transform: uppercase"> Quality meets efficiency, yet so affordable </h3>
                <p style="color:white;"> We work hard to deliver great website designs efficiently,<br> while you pay ress than the crowd.      
        </div>

    </div>
    </div>

</div>



<div class="three" id="provide">
    <div id="whatWeProvide">
    <h3 align="center" style="font-size: 35px; text-decoration: capitalize;"> What do we provide?   </h3>
    <hr class="header_line">
    <br><br>
    <div style="margin-top: 6%">
        <div align="center" class="col-sm-4">
                <span id="span" style="color:white; font-size: 80px; margin-left: 5%" class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
                <h3 style="color: white; text-transform: uppercase"> You're preferences </h3>
                <p style="color: white;"> You tell us what you want the website to look like and <br> we'll start tinkering to produce the final image! </p>
        </div>
        <div align="center" class="col-sm-4">
                <span style="color:white; font-size: 80px; margin-left: 8%" class="glyphicon glyphicon-forward"></span>
                <h3 style="color: white; text-transform: uppercase"> fast and reliable </h3>
                <p style="color: white;"> Once we comfirm your request, we will being working on it <br> right away. </p>
        </div>
        <div id="oddOneOut" align="center" class="col-sm-4">
                <span style="color:white; font-size: 80px; margin-left: 5%" class="glyphicon glyphicon-usd"></span>
                <h3 style="color: white; text-transform: uppercase"> Quality meets efficiency, yet so affordable </h3>
                <p style="color:white;"> We work hard to deliver great website designs efficiently,<br> while you pay ress than the crowd.      
        </div>

    </div>
    </div>
</div>



<div class="four" id="contactUs">

</div>






</body>
</html>
```

This is the CSS code:

```
body{ 
opacity:0;
transition: opacity 0.5s;
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s; /* Safari */
}
div{
    height:100vh; 
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
h1, h2, h3{
    color: white;
    font-family: Avant Garde,Avantgarde,Century Gothic,CenturyGothic,AppleGothic,sans-serif;    
}
p{
    color: white;
    font-family: Avant Garde,Avantgarde,Century Gothic,CenturyGothic,AppleGothic,sans-serif; 
}
#infoHeader{
    height: 10%;
    background-color: #1A1C27; 
    position: fixed;
    top:0px;
    z-index: 999;

}
.header_line{
    width: 10%;
}
.header a{
    position: relative;
    top: 5%;
    transform: translateY(5%);
    margin: 10px;
}
a{
    position: relative;
    background: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-clip: border-box;
    border: 2px solid #1A1C27;
    color: #ffffff;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 40px;
    display: inline-block;
    zoom: 1;
    box-shadow: none;
    text-shadow: none;

}
a:hover{
    /* This says that when the user hovers over
    the button, it will turn blue within a 500ms effect duration */
    color: #00ffbf;
     border: 2px solid #00ffbf;
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 500ms ease;
    -ms-transition: all 500ms ease;
    -o-transition: all 500ms ease;
    transition: all 500ms ease;
}
.one{

    background-image: url("street_lamps.jpg");
    background-size: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.two{
    background-color: #1A1C27;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
#WhyUsHeader{
    position: relative;
    top: 25%;
    left: 25%;
}
.three{
    background-color: #f7c500;
}
```

In between .two and .three in the final result is a white space separating the two which is really annoying and gives it an unprofessional look. I tried overflow-x: hidden on .two and .three because I thought that that would've fixed the problem as it did between the menu header and .one. This did not work. I tried searching and saw some results that also did not work. Anyone knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of things you can do to fix this. I changed the following and works for me:

```
.three{
    background-color: #f7c500;
    margin-top: -20px;
}

div{
    height:120vh; 
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

The height of the `div` is increased and the margin is added to `.three` div.

```
<h3 align="center" style="font-size: 35px; text-decoration: capitalize; padding-top: 20px;"> What do we provide?</h3>
```

The padding is also added for the `<h3>` to have margin from the above div to look nice.